# Getting error about PyQt5 when using Virtual Environment on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyqt5, virtualenv, xcb, qtplugin

I'm building a project with PyQt5 and I've changed my operating system Windows to Ubuntu. On Windows, everything was going perfect with virtual environments but since i changed my OS and tried to launch my first qt app, i'm getting the error down below.

Additionally, it works clearly without Virtual Env.

First of all, I've created my virtual environment with python3-venv module.
Then, i activated the environment and install PyQt5 with pip.

Then I just tried run the project.

`python3 main.py`

## Output:

`qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Canceled (core dumped)`

Comment: You probably need to put your site-packages directory on your `PATH`

Comment: In my case I upgraded `pip install --upgrade pip` into the latest version which in this date `pip-23.2` and I was able to install `PyQt5` successfully without any issues